# Define a function that updates the <title>attribute of a webpage

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is what I am tasked with:

Define a function named titleLinks. Upon being called, the titleLinks function shall update the title attribute of every link on the current page to the following:   This is a link to: href

Here is what I have so far:

```
function titleLinks(){
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('title'); //gets array-like list of titles
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        titleLinks[i]
        console.log "This is a link to:" <href>
    }
```

Also; I know basically how to use chrome developer tool to see what happens but how do I invoke this once I get it coded correctly?

Comment: You mean once this function called you want to update every title of the page?

Comment: A few quick point-outs to get you started: **(1)** You're missing a closing `}`  **(2)** I'd imagine if you're looking for *links* (which are denoted as `<a>`), you'll want to `getElementsByTagName('a')`, rather than `'title'`.  **(3)** `titleLinks[i]`  is close, but i think you want `var currentLink = table[i];`.  **(4)** `console.log` is a function, and the value to be logged is passed in like so: `console.log( <value here> )`.  **(5)** In summary, do some research on changing an element's attributes, and string concatenation.

Comment: Also, *"The `<title>` element of a webpage"* is something completely different than a link `title` attribute. Your title does not match the task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you Tyler for clarifying some of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Couple of changes.

Instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('title');` you want links (`<a>` element). The `<title>` element goes in the `<head>` once, and defines the title of the page.

Once you have the links, you can use `.getAttribute('href');` to get the href.

Then to apply your new title, you can use `.setAttribute('title', 'your value')`

Full example:

```
function titleLinks() {
    let table = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); //gets array-like list of links
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      let thisHref = table[i].getAttribute('href')
      table[i].setAttribute('title', "This is a link to:" + thisHref);
    }
}
```

To call the function in your code you can then use `titleLinks();` you can also type that into console to run your function (if you have already defined it in a .js file or in console.)

Documentation:

- [`<title>` Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) vs. [title attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)
- [.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
- [.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: Thank you very much Sam for the help. I find that I get held up in areas like; 'for statements' (defining a variable and using something like table.length within that for loop). I hope that makes sense. I'll continue to ask questions here and learn as much as I can and eventually contribute.

Comment: No problem. If you are happy with this answer you can 'accept' it.